# Hangman game in asp.net / c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I was trying to create the hangman game in asp .net using c#, but since I am a beginner in this field, I got stuck.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public static string GetRandomWords()
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 Word, Description FROM Hangman ORDER BY NEWID()");

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = query;

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Append(reader["Word"].ToString());
            result.Append(reader["Description"].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Now this gives me one string that looks like this: ElephantHugeanimal. Do you have any idea how can i separate this into two textboxes? Elephant in the first one, and the description in the other?

Comment: Okay, what's your question?

Comment: dont use append. Store the word and the description in seperate strings. As far as masking and guessing, that all depends on how you wish to display the game

Answer (score 2):

```
result.AppendFormat(@"{0} | {1}", reader["Word"], reader["Description"]);
```

Just for suggestion, you might want to use using statement for every object that implements idisposable